# SteamCommunity Api PriceHistory PHP

Tags: php, steam-web-api

Доброго времени суток всем. Возникла одна задачка, не знаю, как к ней подойти, чтобы решить её. В общем: долго ковырясь со своим проектом по анализингу цен в Стим Маркете, наткнулся на этот фанкшн - http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=440&market_hash_name=Specialized%20Killstreak%20Brass%20Beast

Судя по его логике, он отдает полную историю продажи этого предмета в Маркете Стима. Есть загвоздка. Его использовать можно только в авторизированном состоянии.

Варианты:

1. Данная страничка подтягивает печенюху с названием SteamLoginSecure и
   выдает информацию.
2. Стим дает разрешение на вывод информации, если текущая сессия
   пользователя с этого браузера активна.

Может я и не прав, отрицать и спорить не стану, но мне жутко интересно, может кто-то может помочь вытащить через `file_get_contents()` данную байду?

Просто если делать это без авторизации, то ответ будет пустым массивом. В то же время, если вы не залогинетесь в Стиме, то у них, на странице продажи предмета, PriceHistory доступен в оффлайн режиме. Как так?

Comment: а с токеном стима не работает? (я не проверял)

Comment: Да кабы я знал, это функция нужна в единичном случае. Нужно для библиотеки получить эти ценники по запросу, а как их вытаскивать через file_get_contents, если он хочет чтобы я авторизированным был? Как в принципе без JSON и различных ботов под консольную шляпу сделать эту авторизацию?

Comment: ну я же говорю. У стима есть специальный токен, который можно получить если ты разработчик. Точную ссылку не скажу, но в интернете можно найти как его получить. Он в принципе тебя и авторизует на сервисе, как приложение и ты можешь получить доступ ко многим вещам, и пользоваться самим SteamAPI

Comment: Ну я, лично, предполагаю, что ты про Steam Api-key. Если нет, то хотелось бы попоробнее узнать об этой фиче.

Comment: да, я про Api-key (он же токен для авторизации на сервисе, для работы с апи). Он не предоставляет возможность открывать страницы с помощью этого токена (если память не изменяет надо добавить &key=SteamAPIKey как параметр к адресу). Я когда делал, но немного для другой страницы у меня все это работало

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, эта страничка не включена в Апишник стима, в отличии от хешнеймов и аппид-ов. Тут даже ключ не нужен для него. Нужно как-то отправить в хеадере данные об авторизации, кои я не могу даже выполнить с обычной php странички.

Answer (score 1):

Вам, вероятно, подойдёт авторизация с помощью CURL, а дальше действуйте по привычной схеме

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А есть может у Вас примерчик подобного на курлах?) А то я, скажем по-честному, не знаю как это сделать(

Comment: Не могу дать рабочий код для steam, ибо понятия не имею как работать с их двухфакторной авторизацией. Уверен лишь в том что CURL это умеет.

Comment: Да мне же не доступ к Апи нужен, двух-факторная на аккаунте для тестов отключена, логин и пароль только